# Football players' twitter accounts

Tags: football, twitter

Is there anywhere a ~comprehensive list of top football players and their twitter accounts?

Answer (score 2):

Nearly all top football players have a Wikipedia article, in a language or another, so they also have a Wikidata item.

Such Wikidata items often have a [Twitter username](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P2002) property.

You can get the data via a SPARQL query. like this:

```
SELECT ?item ?twitter
WHERE 
{
  ?item wdt:P106 wd:Q937857. # Occupation: football player
  OPTIONAL{?item wdt:P2002 ?twitter}
}
```

[Try it](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3Ftwitter%20%23%3FitemLabel%0AWHERE%20%0A%7B%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP106%20wd%3AQ937857.%20%23%20Occupation%3A%20football%20player%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP2002%20%3Ftwitter%7D%0A%20%20%23SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22.%20%7D%20%23%20Helps%20get%20the%20label%20in%20your%20language%2C%20if%20not%2C%20then%20en%20language%0A%7D)

It currently returns 336281 footballers, among whom 6762 have a Twitter username.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured out that Transfermarkt has a section "social media" on players' profiles. Next step is to scrape it

[image]